# Testing a minimal livedata viewmodel using Mockito

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, android-room, android-livedata

I have the following viewmodel:

```
class ListViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val appDatabase: AppDatabase by lazy {
        AppDatabase.getInstance(application)
    }

    private val items: LiveData<List<Item>> by lazy {
        appDatabase.itemDao().getAllItems()
    }

    fun getAllItems(): LiveData<List<Item>> {
        return items
    }

    fun deleteItemById(id: Long) {
        launch { async { appDatabase.itemDao().deleteItemById(id) } }
    }
}
```

I have a test suite already in place at the DAO level, and because this viewmodel is simple an abstraction layer over my DAOs, I'm struggling to figure out how to create meaningful tests for this viewmodel.

I've tried mocking the DAOs using Mockito but can't seem to implement them properly. My latest attempt looks like this:

```
class ListViewModelTest {

    lateinit var listViewModel: ListViewModel

    @Mock
    lateinit var context: Application

    @Mock
    lateinit var appDatabase: AppDatabase

    @Mock
    lateinit var items: LiveData<List<Item>>

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        setupMocks()
        listViewModel = ListViewModel(context)
    }

    fun setupMocks() {
        `when`<Context>(context.applicationContext).thenReturn(context)
        `when`(appDatabase.itemDao().getAllItems()).thenReturn(items)
    }

    @Test
    fun getAllItems() {
        listViewModel.getAllItems()
        verify(appDatabase).itemDao().getAllItems()
    }

    @Test
    fun deleteFilesystem() {
        listViewModel.deleteItemById(0)
        verify(appDatabase).itemDao().deleteItemById(0)
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to testing in general, so any general advice is also appreciated.